# How to get the class type of a Blender Collection Property?

Tags: python

I am looking for class types of blender property objects.

I am looping over some properties in a scene and want to operate on them when they are `bpy.types.CollectionProperty`.

My custom property is for example stored in `bpy.data.scene[0].my_custom_collection_prop`

Here is some pseudo code:

```
for key,value in bpy.data.scene[0].items():
    prop = getattr(bpy.data.scene[0],key)
    if type(prop) == bpy.types.CollectionProperty:
        do something
```

`type(prop)` gives me `<class 'bpy_prop_collection_idprop'>` which is not `bpy.types.CollectionProperty`. So I don't know how to compare both.

---

Here is an example showing whats intended, it runs but doesn't find the type:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, CollectionProperty

class MyCollectionProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = StringProperty(default="")


bpy.utils.register_class(MyCollectionProperty)
bpy.types.Scene.my_collection_prop = CollectionProperty(
        type=MyCollectionProperty)

scene = bpy.data.scenes[0]
for attr in dir(scene):
    prop = getattr(scene, attr, None)
    if prop is not None:
        if type(prop) == bpy.types.CollectionProperty:
            print(prop)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ID.items()` is going to give you **custom-properties**, which is lower level and bypasses properties created by [`bpy.props`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html), I suspect you want to iterate over attributes, instead of custom-properties.

You can do this instead:

```
scene = bpy.data.scenes[0]
for attr in dir(scene):
    value = getattr(scene, attr)
    if type(value) == bpy.types.CollectionProperty:
        print("something", attr, value)
```

The example above uses Python's [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) functions, you can also use a Blender specific method of introspecting properties.

```
scene = bpy.data.scene[0]
for attr in scene.bl_rna.properties.keys():
    value = getattr(scene, attr)
    if type(value) == bpy.types.CollectionProperty:
        print("something", attr, value)
```

This limits the properties to Blender's data-api, and wont include functions for example.

---

Here is a working example based on the example in your question:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, CollectionProperty

class MyCollectionProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = StringProperty(default="")


bpy.utils.register_class(MyCollectionProperty)
bpy.types.Scene.my_collection_prop = CollectionProperty(
        type=MyCollectionProperty)

scene = bpy.data.scenes[0]
for attr in dir(scene):
    prop = getattr(scene, attr, None)
    if isinstance(prop, bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection):
        if bpy.types.Scene.bl_rna.properties[attr].fixed_type == MyCollectionProperty.bl_rna:
            print(prop, "found")
```

This used Blender specific data-api introspection (`bl_rna`).

Note: You may want to use [`isinstance`](http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/do_not_compare_types_use_isinstance.html).

Comment: it seems type(value) == bpy.types.CollectionPropeHrrty is not the same.

Here is an example file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ulhscx54oti1bq/property_type.blend?dl=0

Comment: You should writing `scene = bpy.data.scene[0]` with an `s` to `scenes` if you expect sth run !

Comment: Corrected the error.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which doesn't rely on knowing the collection items' type beforehand.

Get the property special dictionary construct by accessing the holder's ([bpy_struct.id_data](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=id_data#bpy.types.bpy_struct.id_data)) custom properties (barely documented `bl_rna.properties`), and get the property by name using [bpy_struct.path_from_id](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html?highlight=path_from_id#bpy.types.bpy_struct.path_from_id).

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, CollectionProperty

class MyCollectionProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = StringProperty(default="")

bpy.utils.register_class(MyCollectionProperty)
bpy.types.Scene.my_collection_prop = CollectionProperty(type=MyCollectionProperty)

def get_class(collection_prop: bpy.types.CollectionProperty) -> type:
    prop = collection_prop.id_data.bl_rna.properties.get(collection_prop.path_from_id())
    return type(prop.fixed_type) if prop is not None else None

assert MyCollectionProperty == get_class(bpy.data.scenes[0].my_collection_prop)
```

Note this will only work if the `bpy.props.CollectionProperty` is a direct member of a `bpy.types.ID` instance. In the case where a collection property is held in a property group you can use something like :

```
def get_class(collection_prop: bpy.types.CollectionProperty) -> type:
    holder_path = ".".join(repr(collection_prop).split(".")[:-1])  # Get the path to the prop and remove the last element
    holder = eval(holder_path)
    prop_name = repr(collection_prop).split(".")[-1]
    return type(holder.bl_rna.properties.get(prop_name).fixed_type)
```

It's a bit more hacky but more extendable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :) I have a small tweak so we avoid a loop. It seems like `.id_data.bl_rna.properties` behaves like a `dict` and the following works too: `return type(collection_prop.id_data.bl_rna.properties[collection_prop.path_from_id()].fixed_type)` (you might want to have intermediate variables for readability)

Comment: @AlexLoss Oh right that makes sense ! Thank you I'll fix it.