# Creating a copy of a bpy_prop_collection instance?

Tags: python

This may be a basic question but I'm digging through the reference and can't figure it out.

```
isinstance(bpy.context.scene.objects, bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection)
```

returns

```
True
```

How can I make a full (or partial) copy of the objects currently in `bpy.context.scene.objects`, as an instance of `bpy.types.bpy_prop_collection`?

I want to basically take a "snapshot" of the current objects in the scene that won't change if objects are added or deleted later.

But it also needs to be a bpy_prop_collection instance in order to use the foreach_get/set methods.

I *think?* [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55424/34386) might have some clues but I can't quite figure out how to apply it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Save as a library**

Possibly the simplest way to do this is to save the required objects to a library

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene
dump = [scene]
dump.extend(o for o in scene.objects)

bpy.data.libraries.write(
        "/tmp/scene_dump.blend",          
        set(dump), 
        fake_user=True, 
        compress=True)
```

then link or append back as req'd (py console code)

```
>>> with D.libraries.load("/tmp/scene_dump.blend") as (src, dest):
...     src.scenes
...     src.objects
...     
['Scene']
['Suzanne', 'Speaker', 'Camera.001']
```

**Have a look at `rna_***` modules**

In the **`2.XX/scripts/modules/`** folder you will find some modules prefixed with "rna_".  Check them out for an exhaustive guide on how to navigate blenders rna.

An example of using `rna_xml.py` to dump the context scene into a file.

```
import bpy
from rna_xml import rna2xml

scene = bpy.context.scene

scene_dump = "/tmp/scenedump.xml"

with open(scene_dump, "wt") as f:
    rna2xml(fw=f.writelines, 
    root_rna=scene,
    root_node="Scene")
```

A small snippet of the 100+ megabyte file produced

```
  <objects>
    <Object name="Cube"
            users="1"
            use_fake_user="FALSE"
            tag="FALSE"
            is_library_indirect="FALSE"
            library="NONE"
            override_static="NONE"
            data="Mesh::Cube"
            type="MESH"
            mode="OBJECT"
            layers_local_view="FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE"
            bound_box="-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1"
            parent="NONE"
            parent_type="OBJECT"
```

Comment: Really good info, thanks! I'm not totally sure how to use it yet but I'll definitely study it. I was naively hoping I could do something like `selObjs = {o for o in objs if o.select}` (just the selected objects as a Collection) and then do something like `selObjs.foreach_get('color', list)` since the foreach methods are so insanely fast, but only work on Collections.