# How to get the class type associated to a Blender Collection Property?

Tags: python, collections

EDIT: Question has been answered [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/268335/150988)

Given a known and empty `CollectionProperty(type=MyCollectionProperty)`, how do I retrieve the related python class? (in this case `MyCollectionProperty`)

Example:

```py
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, CollectionProperty

class MyCollectionProperty(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = StringProperty(default="")


bpy.utils.register_class(MyCollectionProperty)
bpy.types.Scene.my_collection_prop = CollectionProperty(type=MyCollectionProperty)

def get_class(collection_prop: bpy.types.CollectionProperty) -> type:
    # TODO
    pass

assert MyCollectionProperty == get_class(bpy.data.scenes[0].my_collection_prop)
```

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55423/how-to-get-the-class-type-of-a-blender-collection-property) has been answered by assuming the class beforehand. How do I get the class without iterating over all possible classes and without accessing it's items?

Comment: Hello, to prevent information scattering I answered directly on the other Q&A